# For nonempty sets $A \subset M, B \subset N$, if $A \times B$ is compact, then $A$ and $B$ are compact.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, proof-verification, compactness

Consider any pair of sequences $(a_n) \subset A$ and $(b_n) \subset B.$ The sequence $((a_n),(b_n)) \subset A \times B$ is contained in $A \times B.$ Hence, there is a subsequence $(a_{f(n)}, b_{g(n)}) \subset A \times B$ whose limit $(a',b') \in A \times B.$ It follows that $(a_{f(n)}) \subset (a_n) \subset A$ and $(b_{g(n)}) \subset (g_n) \subset B,$ that is, $(a_{f(n)})$ is a subsequence of the sequence $(a_n),$ which is contained in $A,$ and $(b_{g(n)})$ is a subsequence of the sequence $(b_n),$ which is contained in $B.$ Moreover, it also follows from $(a',b') \in A \times B$ that $a' \in A$ and $b' \in B.$ Therefore, the subsequences $(a_{f(n)})$ of $(a_n) \subset A$ and $(b_{g(n)})$ of $(b_n) \subset B$ have their limits $a'$ and $b',$ respectively, in $A$ and $B,$ respectively. Hence, $A$ and $B$ are compact.

Is there something missing in this proof?

**Definition of compactness in the textbook**:

"A subset $A$ of a metric space $M$ is (sequentially) **compact** if every sequence $(a_n)$ in $A$ has a subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ that converges to a limit in $A.$

This is the only definition of compactness mentioned in the textbook.

Comment: This is sequence compactness. Compactness per se is possibly even simpler: Let $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ be an open cover of $A$. Then $\{U_i\times B\}_{i\in I}$ is an open cover of $A\times B$, hence has a finite subcover. This translates into a finite subcover of $A$.

Comment: Hey Hagen! We have not yet covered covers in our class. I can't decipher your comment! :(

Comment: The title is very misleading. You have $A\subset M$, $B\subset N$ and $A\times B$ is compact, if I correctly read the question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback greg. I changed it. Let me know if it is still misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine as long as you are working in spaces in which sequentially compact $\Leftrightarrow$ compact, e.g metrizable spaces. But this is also true for more general spaces. Indeed, when $A\times B$ has the product topology, the maps $\pi_A: A\times B \rightarrow A$, $\pi_B: A\times B \rightarrow B$ defined as the projections are continuous. Since continuous maps send compact to compact, then $A=\pi_A(A\times B)$, $B=\pi_B(A\times B)$ are both compact.

Comment: I made a mistake. I will edit: The problem is writ as follows: "Assume that the Cartesian product of two nonempty sets $A \subset M$ and $B \subset N$ is compact in $M \times N$ prove that $A$ and $B$ are compact. The problem does not state that $M$ and $N$ are metric spaces. Is that a mistake?

Comment: Your statement is true for any $M, N$ topological spaces, what fails to be correct is your original proof because it assumes the at least $A, B$ are sequentially compact iff compact. My proof works in the general setting. But indeed, your proof is correct for metrizable spaces. you just have to be careful and differentiate both definitions of compactness.

Comment: Ok. I'm looking at the definition of compactness in my textbook. The author has written "(sequentially)" **compact**. He has not spoken of any other form of compactness. So, I think that by "compact," he means sequentially compact?

Comment: Take a look at Munkres Topology 2nd Edition, page 179 to see the three main types of compactness and the differences between them.

Comment: Ok. Thanks Laz :)

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

There's an assumption missing: that neither $A$ nor $B$ is empty. Otherwise, the proof fails (and the statment is false, by the way).

That argument works for metric spaces. For general topological spaces it doesn't because, in general, it is not true that a topological space is compact if and only if every sequence has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: I made a mistake. I will edit: The problem is writ as follows: "Assume that the Cartesian product of two nonempty sets $A \subset M$ and $B \subset N$ is compact in $M \times N$ prove that $A$ and $B$ are compact. The problem does not state that $M$ and $N$ are metric spaces. Is that a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You have only proved sequentially compactness.  For metric (or metrizable) spaces this is equivalent to compactness, but for general topological spaces it isn't.  However, there is an easy fix replacing sequences with nets to work with arbitrary topological spaces $M,N$.

Comment: Hey. The concept "net" has not been introduced in the textbook!